# Getting print_r from a Drupal variable

Tags: drupal

I have a Drupal variable, $view. I need to print out all of its values. I have tried:

```
dsm($view);

var_dump($view);

function hook_form_alter() {
    $form['print'] = array('#value' => '<pre>'.print_r($view, 1).'</pre>');
}
```

All of these functions produce an output of `Null`, however. How can I get the value of the variable?

Comment: What doesn't work about them? I don't have Drupal, so maybe if you post the output of these commands, I can try to help.

Comment: It does not display any output on the screen. For the var_dump() and print_r, it just displays null null

Comment: Is the variable `Null`? The output could be correct.

Comment: no, its an array $value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably happening because the $view variable isn't within scope in the function hook_form_alter().

Comment: Try `dsm(get_defined_vars());` or `var_dump(get_defined_vars());` to see which variables are available at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$view = views_get_current_view();
```

Then you can access, for example, the arguments of the view:

```
$arg0 = $view->args[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id){
  switch($form_id){
    case 'MY_FORM':
      $display_id  = 'block_1';
      $view        = views_get_view('my_view_machine_name');

      $view->set_display($display_id)
      $view->set_items_per_page(0); // or other
      $view->execute();
      $result = $view->preview();

      // Also you can use $view->result to get result as array

      $form['print'] = $result;
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.